# Splint : Cannot open file

Tags: makefile, splint

When trying to run an analysis on my project with Splint via makefile I got this error message :

```
Cannot open file: ../splint_evaluationa/my_project/source/*.c

Finished checking --- no code processed
```

Here is my makefile:

```
SPLINT_FLAGS =-preproc  \
              -warnposixheaders       \
SRCS=/home/user/splint_evaluationa/my_project/source/*.c
INC_FLAGS=-I/home/user/splint_evaluation/my_project/include

do_splint:
      splint $(SPLINT_FLAGS) $(INC_FLAGS) $(SRCS)
```

Comment: The trailing backslash on the `-warnposixheaders` line is incorrect.

Comment: I got the same error without the backslash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a extra `a`, try that instead:

```
SRCS=/home/user/splint_evaluation/my_project/source/*.c
```

Comment: You're right I didn't notice this... I'm sorry it doesn't deserve to be published as an analysis problem...